# Determing when lead acid battery is parallel through embedded systems

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, inverter, microchip, charger

I have browsed my fingers out but I just can't get close to what my needs are.

I am trying to work out a solution whereby my charger should charge a 200ah lead acid battery at a specific current, but once the battery is paralleled with another 200ah making it 400ah, my charger should know and increase the charging Current by 2.

Can someone help out with some stunt, I would really be grateful.

Comment: Did you design the charger? Can it handle 2x current?

Comment: You cannot/should not connect batteries in parallel like that. If there is a difference in charge level then the one with the most charge will start charging the one with less charge. Lead Acid batteries, especially 200 Ah ones, can deliver **HUGE** currents and such a large current will cause problems like **melting wires** etc. You should only connect batteries in parallel after they are **balanced**. Besides that there is no need to increase the charging current, charging will simply take 2x as long. -1 for messing with powerful SLA batteries while not understanding them.

Comment: Yes, I designed it to handle very high current. The reason behind my quest it's for the instance where I see the need to parallel batteries, thus I shouldn't be redesigning charging Current. Sure, the paralleled batteries would be balanced before such adventure is embarked. As for cabling melting, I already took care of that.  The reason why there need be an increase in current is because I observed currently that the batteries quietly shared the charge current in two's when parralled,  thereby reducing the charge current to each by half. This thus is increasing the charge time.

Comment: Am sure my position is well understood, if so,  then comes the puzzle thrown up at first. How do I beat this, say,  using microcontroller... Arduino or PIC, any one would be ok by me...!

Comment: *using microcontroller... Arduino or PIC* That's the trouble with electronics today, many beginners think that almost any problem can be solved by using a microcontroller. They don't see / think about the real challenges like how to implement the circuit between batteries and micro. Once that is in place the micro is trivial.

Comment: It is a good question that needs a technical answer

Answer (score 2):

## Theory proposed in question

A Smart Battery charger ought to know how to regulated charge current from the number of batteries connected to a charge node.

===============

## My logic

In new batteries it is possible to correlate very well between ESR and equivalent capacitance in kilofarads in a 2nd order RC//RC model by testing for any given production line or controlled supplier quality.  But defects or aging effects will present big differences in ESR.

This means the capacity vs ESR=dV/dI and C=Ic*dt/dV can be correlated well with Ah with actual test result.

However it has been confirmed by reports in Battery University that this is not a good correlation between ESR and Ah capacity for many reasons due to mismatch. ( ref. not handy)

- If I may rationalize this opinion, we **cannot assume** the cell-ambient thermal resistance, Rja, of batteries is the same for all types of similar Ah capacities or that all Ah batteries share identical ESR.

The cell temperature rise can have higher ESR in one cell or pack more than the other and thus the current is not shared equally. $$ T(rise)=  Rja * ESR * I^2 = ['C/W] * [W]$$

- When heat rise is added to acid, it can boil and create combustible gases (H2, O2)

### Busted

- Therefore is unsafe for any battery charger to look at a shared node current and voltage and prediction the max current charge rate without the user manually setting the max rate.

## Alternative solution

Have separate current regulated ports or a programmable setting.

Comment: "Have separate current regulated ports or a programmable setting"  seems promising. I'd really love it if you can expand this idea way further. With all said, this catch the eye, please enlighten me more. Many regards

Comment: Do you know how to monitor current with a 50mV shunt and control it with PWM. You then make them separate for each output then optimize pulse positions for minimum overlap while computing Vrms and Irms (or average) against target profile for CC and CV vs temp (ideally). Series air coil chokes can store some energy if you compute for minimal Q and yet high efficiency without exceeding battery specs.  But simplest solution are independent motor/alternators with independent field current controlled 3phase rectified output current.

Comment: Yes, I do. If I get you right, there is higher current presence at shunt when battery capacity increases. Wow, never thought of this. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

While I don't share your optimism that you know what you're doing, I'll suggest two approaches.

Note that a constant-current charge is only appropriate in the early stages of the charge process, typically charging the battery to about 70% of full charge. After that, a constant voltage should be applied. That you do not speak of this phase suggests that you are not treating your batteries properly, and so I'm dubious that you possess the competence which you seem to think you do.

Approach the first: Start at 200 A. Monitor the rate at which the battery voltage rises. If you have two batteries in parallel, the voltage will rise half as quickly as if you had one. Once you've established the rate of voltage rise (and compensated for state of charge and battery voltage - the rate will vary with both) that charger can decide whether or not to switch to 400 A.

Approach the second. Assume separate charge cables from the charger to the battery(s). Start the charge at 200 A. Monitor the voltage drop from the negative battery leads to the charger, using the charger - input as your ground reference point. It is almost certain that at 200 A you'll have enough voltage drop to get a reading. If both leads show a voltage drop, indicating the presence of a battery on both charge circuits, increase the current to 400 amps.

Comment: You may be just right, I sure do not posses the skill presumed. I would appreciate more education if you don't mind.       Warm regards.